# moving a symfony2 project

Tags: symfony

Learning progaming with symfony is a evolutional process (for me). So, I have to do things new I have done, or I have to change them.

Now I have changed the structure of the project. It lives not longer complete in the web directory, it lives now in my user and only a symbolic link `'projectname'-> 'User/.../procektname/web'` is in the web directory.
Before this Change, I have to start the app in the browser with `http://localhost/dev_app.php/`, now it is `http:localhost/project/dev_app.php`. It runs fine. And I think, so I can run more than one Symfony project on one computer.

But when I start the `config.php` and go through the configuration (database and secret) the `config.php` will write the config data to the old path. Why? Is there anything to do after moving the project?

P.S. I think its harder than I wrote. You must know, that I have not moved my project, I have made a copy and moved the copy. A view minutes ago, I have done following: Changing the name of the original. And now nothing runs!

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

ends with a RuntimeExeption, and I can see, it will clear the cache at the old path!

Comment: Did you fixed it? If so, you can post your answer to your question and accept it as the answer. If not, maybe this cookbook article will help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I delete the cache by hand and the App runs. At least there is the question why I get the Exeption when I clear the cash with the console. But I think it is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem than carp-enter.
And Wouter J posted exactly the right symfony link.
We need to override getters for paths.
After, it works very fine.